# Sharepoint API - possible deprecation

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have an app that currently uses the Sharepoint API and uses resources, such as:

`_api/web/GetFileById('ID')`

Other parts of the app, deal with importing users/groups from Azure Active Directory API.

I've seen that the AAD API is being phased out later tis year and I'm currently in the process of replacing the AAD code to use the Graph API library

I know the docs suggest to use Graph API over the Sharepoint API, but does this mean that the Sharepoint API is also being phased out, similarly to the AAD API?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint REST API provides a large set of endpoints and capabilities that are not available today in the Microsoft Graph.
If the Microsoft Graph is working on providing more and more endpoints and capabilities for SharePoint, it is going to take years for them to close the gaps, if they ever do.
Today the rationale is simple: use the graph if it provides all you need for new applications or new features in existing applications, and leverage the SharePoint REST API when the capabilities you need aren't exposed though the Graph.
Microsoft hasn't announced any depreciation of the SharePoint REST API in favor to the Graph to date and is not instructing developers to migrate existing applications like it has for applications using EWS or AAD endpoints.
That might change three to five years down the road but again, no information on that sense has been shared by Microsoft today.

Comment: Fantastic! That was my major concern as the app is legacy and uses the Sharepoint API extensively in parts, whilst it uses the AAD API only in a couple of places. I'm happy to use the Graph to replace the AAD stuff